# Adding a citation inside a citation with natbib

Tags: citing, natbib

I want to get the following kind of citation using `natbib`, is that possible?

> "some guy said this" (SomeGuy, 2010, as cited in SomeOtherGuy, 2013)

I can do this manually by writing:

```
"some guy said this" \citep[as cited in SomeOtherGuy, 2013]{someguykey2010}
```

but I would much rather have the second reference be a reference in itself.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Do you mean something like this?

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{filecontents}

\begin{filecontents}{\jobname.bib}
@article{someguykey2010,
author="SomeGuy",
title="A journal article",
year=2010,
journal="A Journal",
}
@article{someotherguykey2013,
author="SomeOtherGuy",
title="A journal article",
year=2013,
journal="A Journal",
}
\end{filecontents}

\usepackage[round]{natbib}

\begin{document}

``some guy said this'' \citep[as cited in \citealp{someotherguykey2013}]{someguykey2010}

\bibliographystyle{plainnat}
\bibliography{\jobname}

\end{document}
```

[image]

If you want, you can even define a new command `\doublecitep`

```
\newcommand{\doublecitep}[2]{\citep[as cited in \citealp{#2}]{#1}}
```

and use it like

```
\doublecitep{someguykey2010}{someotherguykey2013}
```

instead of

```
\citep[as cited in \citealp{someotherguykey2013}]{someguykey2010}
```

Comment: I can't believe I didn't even try that. I just assumed I couldn't use commands in an option.